# File ended while scanning use of \href

Tags: bibtex, citing, texstudio, elsarticle, href

I am really new to LaTeX. I am using elsarticle document class, TeXstudio and BiBdesk to prepare my manuscript. I keep getting "File ended while scanning use of \href. ...FILE PATH/P001-bibtex}" error.

I used the following code in my tex file. My last two citations were undefined.

I was trying to look online but no luck. I am super frustrated hope you guys could help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[preprint,review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}

\biboptions{sort&compress}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \begin{abstract}
            
        \end{abstract}  
    
        \begin{keyword}
        
        \end{keyword}
            
    \end{frontmatter}

    \linenumbers
        
    \section{Introduction}

    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
    \bibliography{/Users/keatbin/Desktop/P001_manuscript/P001-bibtex}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Log]
[[image: Screenshot of the Log File2]

Comment: Guess the problem came from your bib file.

Comment: Yes but I cannot pinpoint it. It's the curly bracket right?

Comment: You could bisect the bib file. Oh wait, the problem is probably near the line containing arxiv link in your second screenshot.

Comment: I have tried that (using Find function) but my bib file does not contain any refrences from Arxiv.

Comment: Ah, the line under `Runaway argument?` in your second screenshot might came from some `doi` entry in your bib file. If you have bisected the bib to a reasonable size and its contents are not sensitive, you can post it so others can help you further more.